# Saving arrays of iOS Apps

Tags: arrays, ios, save, device

I would like to know how to save arrays of my iOS app. I used a method, but it only saved on my iPod Touch. I'd tested on iPad and it didn't work.

What I need is a code to save my app array on any device...

Anyone can help me?

Here is the code:

myAppViewController.h:

```
- (NSString *)GetApplicationDocumentsDirectory;
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(NSNotification *)notification;
```

myAppViewController.m:

```
-(NSString*) GetApplicationDocumentsDirectory {
    static NSString* documentsDirectory = nil;
    if (documentsDirectory == nil) {
        documentsDirectory = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                                   NSUserDomainMask,
                                                                   YES)
                               objectAtIndex:0] retain];

    }
    NSString *fullFileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/TarefasSalvas.plist", documentsDirectory];
    return fullFileName;
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(NSNotification *)notification{
    NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
                             [array addObject:lisTitulos];
                             [array addObject:lisImagens];
                             [array addObject:lisData];
                             [array addObject:lisDetalhes];

    [array writeToFile:[self GetApplicationDocumentsDirectory] atomically:YES]; 
}


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *filePath = [self GetApplicationDocumentsDirectory];
    //if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath]) {
        NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    if (array != nil){
        lisTitulos = [array objectAtIndex:0];
        lisImagens = [array objectAtIndex:1];
        lisData = [array objectAtIndex:2];
        lisDetalhes = [array objectAtIndex:3];
    }
    else {
        NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormat setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
        [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/YYYY"];
        NSString *dateNow = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];

        lisTitulos = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Titulo",nil];
        lisImagens = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"0.png",nil];
        lisData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:dateNow,nil];
        lisDetalhes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"",nil];
    }

    UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(applicationWillTerminate:) name:UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification object:app];
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you tell us exactly what you've done so far with some code and an example?

Comment: What is an "array of [your] iOS app"? What exactly are you trying to save, and where, and when, and what test are you using to determine whether what you have tried has worked?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you're just sending the app to the background and not terminating them. On such occasion, `applicationWillTerminate:` will not be called. That seems to be the likely cause as the rest of the code looks fine.

And your `GetApplicationDocumentsDirectory` seems a bit strangely named as it gets the path to the file in which the array is stored. In addition to that,

```
NSString *fullFileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/TarefasSalvas.plist", documentsDirectory];
```

is not the correct way of getting the file path. You should use the`stringByAppendingPathComponent:` method on `documentsDirectory` like this,

```
NSString *fullFileName = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"TarefasSalvas.plist"];
```

It would also make sense to declare `fullFileName` as the static variable rather than `documentsDirectory`.

Comment: Thanks for replying but, unfortunately, it stills not saving on ipad =/

Comment: Are you sure the method is getting called? And `writeToFile:atomically:` method returns `NO` on failure. You should check what it returns.

Comment: Well, I've noticed that when I run my app on iPad, when I close the app, on bottom of Xcode's screen says: `GDB: Data Formatters temporarlly unavailble, will re-try after "continue".(Not safe to call dlopen at this time.)`

Comment: Seems related to memory problems. Have you tried profiling the app?

Comment: Have you made sure if the method is called and that the write is successful? If not, add an NSLog statement to the `applicationWillTerminate:` method. Put `NSLog(@"method called");` and capture the result of the write operation using `BOOL result = [array writeToFile:[self GetApplicationDocumentsDirectory] atomically:YES];` and then add `NSLog(@"%d",result);` to the end of the method.

Comment: hmm u're right .. Now I see. When I close the app the Debug Terminal dont show the Log:"method called"  and it's returning: `Program received signal:  “SIGKILL”.` on the Debugger Console... How do I call this Method if the iPad is "Killing" my app?? >.<
Detail: My Ipod is Running it normally

Comment: You might be leaking stuff. Implement the `didReceiveMemoryWarning` delegate method in the application delegate and add `NSLog(@"memory warning.");` there.

Comment: Thanks @Deepak I found the solution.
 in about 5 hours or Tomorow I'm going to post what I did to Fix =)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Deepak.
After u giving me the hint about making the Log Alerts on Debugging, I noticed that the iPad is killing the App and then the app can't call the `applicationWillTerminate:` method as you mentioned before.
So I solved the Problem changing my code to:

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(NSNotification *)notification{
    [self SavingStatus];
}

-(void)SavingStatus {
    NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [array addObject:lisTitulos];
    [array addObject:lisImagens];
    [array addObject:lisData];
    [array addObject:lisDetalhes];

    [array writeToFile:[self GetApplicationDocumentsDirectory] atomically:YES]; 
}
```

As you can see, I created a method that I call on `applicationWillTerminate:` method and everytime the app reload the Table data:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

  ...

    [self SavingStatus];

    return cell;

}
```

By this way, even if your device Kill the App before it Close normally, the informations will be saved anyway =D.

Thanks again to @Deepak 
and everybody who replied me.